# How to find nodes at a distance k from the given node in binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

I came across [THIS](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-nodes-distance-k-given-node-binary-tree/) geeksforgeeks post to find nodes at distance k from the given node in a binary tree.

I am not able to understand it even after spending multiple hours. Specially the part to find the nodes at distance k in ancestors.

Can someone please please help me with a small dry run on the code/algorithm in the geeksforgeeks post? Or any other easy to understand solution without using parent pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say the depth of target node is D.

1. If the nodes you want is in the subtree rooted with target node, their depth should be D+k.
2. After that, you need to find all ancestors of the target node.
   For each ancestor, if the depth is d, the distance between this ancestor to the target node is D-d.
   So the final step is to find nodes in the other subtree of this ancestor whose distance is k - (D-d).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I know the basic idea but not able to see how this is getting done in code. :(

Comment: Which parts of the code? `printkdistanceNodeDown(root, k)` find all nodes whose distance to "root" is k under the node "root". `printkdistanceNode()` will check if the target node was found in left subtree (`if (dl != -1)`), right subtree (`if (dr != -1)`), or not its child (`return -1`).

Comment: THanks again. I did not get the right subtree part.

Comment: It's almost the same as the left subtree. `dr` is the distance from current node to your target, or -1 if the target is not part of the right subtree. So, you need to find out all nodes in **left subtree** that the distance is k-dr-2 by this function `printkdistanceNodeDown(root->left, k-dr-2);`.

Comment: I meant to ask when it checks for right subtree. Part where they are saying:  // MIRROR OF ABOVE CODE FOR RIGHT SUBTREE
    // Note that we reach here only when node was not found in left subtree Can we please chat for 5 minutes ?

Comment: Yes, sure. (... but I don't know how to chat here.)